# A question on derangement of n cards with a specific card going into another specific card's envelope.

Tags: combinatorics

In the question stated in: [$6$ cards and $6$ envelopes are numbered $1,2,3,4,5,6$ such that card no. $1$ in always in envelope $2$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2330588/6-cards-and-6-envelopes-are-numbered-1-2-3-4-5-6-such-that-card-no-1-in), I tried extending the question to different numbers of cards and saw a weird pattern. I've manually worked it out for 7 total cards, but can't figure out why the formula works... Here is the formula:
$$P(n) = D(n-1) + D(n-2).$$

Here, $P(n)$ is the derangement where 'n' cards are deranged and one specific card goes into one envelope which is not its own (Ex. Card 1 goes into Envelope 2), and $D(n)$ is a normal derangement of $n$ cards with $n$ respective envelopes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put another way, we want to count the number of permutations $\sigma$ of $\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$ (ie, elements of $S_n$) which are deranged and one specific card goes to one specific envelope, wlog, card 1 in envelope 2, ie, $\sigma(2)=1$

Now, consider what happens to card 2, ie, to which envelope does it go?

If card 2 goes to envelope 1, ie, we also have $\sigma(1)=2$, then our counts correspond to fixing $\sigma(1)=2,~\sigma(2)=1$ and derange the rest, ie, $D(n-2)$

If card 2 **does not** go to envelope 1, ie, $\sigma(1)\ne 2$, we  want to count the number of derangements with $\sigma(2)=1$ and $\sigma(1)\ne 2$. This can be counted equivalently by identifying envelope 1 as envelope 2 in the remaining configuration (ie, disregarding the original envelope 2 since it is already filled with card 1 and relabel envelope 1 as envelope 2, so the task is to simply derange the remaining cards $2,\ldots,n$ in the relabeled envelopes $2,\ldots,n$), ie, $D(n-1)$

Ergo, $P(n)=D(n-1)+D(n-2)$